# PHP : anonymous function in associative array

Tags: php, anonymous-function

Is is possible? Something like (which doesn't work) :

```
$prototype = array(
    'ext' => function ($args)
    {
        $ext = NULL;
        if (in_array(func_get_arg(0), array('js', 'css')))
            return $ext;
        else
            return 'js';
    },
);
```

Comment: have you tried? did it give an error? Do you want "yes" for an answer? Add more information.

Comment: It works fine for me (PHP 5.3.6). Anonymous functions were introduced in PHP 5.3, so make sure you have upgraded.

Comment: It's your syntax that errors =). Remove the `,` after the last `}`.

Comment: @Tim Cooper you're right, I was using 5.2.x without knowing it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The only limitation is that you can't cast it to an object.

```
<?php
    $foo = array(
        'bar' => function($text)
        {
            echo $text;
        }
    );
    $foo['bar']('test'); //prints "test"

    $obj = (object)$foo;
    $obj->bar('test'); //Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::bar() in /code/REGnPf on line 11
?>
```

Comment: So you *can* cast it to an object (there is no error). You get an error later because you're using an undefined method, because there is no method named "bar"; there is a field named "bar". i.e. `$temp = $obj->$bar; $temp();` Fields and methods are completely separate in PHP.

Comment: @newacct, could you suggest a better wording in that case please? :)

Comment: Another limitation is that if that array is part of a property initializer, remember that complicated expressions won't work, which includes anonymous functions.

Answer (score 4):

It certainly is:

```
<?php
$array = array(
        'func' => function($a) {
                return $a + 2;
        }
);
echo $array['func'](3);
?>
```

This will give you 5 =)!